# What is the syntax to sp_recompile logon trigger?

Tags: sql-server-2008, trigger

I would like to recompile my logon trigger using sp_recompile. But I can't figure out the syntax.

E.g. these don't work:

```
sp_recompile '[Tr_Logon]'

sp_recompile '[Tr_Logon]' ON ALL SERVER ;)
```

Comment: Is that a smiley inside your code block? Best to edit that, methinks.

Comment: @MichaelGreen Yes, because that syntax definitely won't work. Some fun is allowed ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think I found it:

[sp_refreshsqlmodule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx) (Books Online)

> Updates the metadata for the specified non-schema-bound stored procedure, user-defined function, view, DML trigger, database-level DDL trigger, or server-level DDL trigger in the current database.

```
EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule
    @name = 'ddl_trig_name',
    @namespace = 'SERVER_DDL_TRIGGER';
```